# Monitor "forgot" its native resolution overnight

Tags: display

I have:

- Hanns G HW173A monitor
- NVIDIA GTX 460 graphics card
- Windows XP SP3.

It *was* working. Suddenly overnight I can no longer use my monitor's native resolution of 1440x900. It's not listed, and if I force it it only shows part of the screen. The only resolution that seems to fit the whole screen is now 1024x768.

I have tried reinstalling the NVIDIA drivers as well as disabling and enabling the monitor drivers (for windows XP the monitor uses the microsoft "default monitor" drivers - this is what Hanns G says on their website too).

Any ideas? Thanks very much.

update: solved by completely removing the VGA cable then putting it back. Must have been loose.

Comment: Some monitors have a factory reset feature in the OSD software on the monitor, might be worth a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loose VGA cable. Even though it didn't seem loose, and had worked without a problem for months, completely undoing it before putting it back seems to have worked.

Comment: Makes sense because the pins communicating EDID information may not have been fully connected.

Comment: Had the same problem here, although with a different monitor and graphics card; exact same solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try the monitor on another computer. If the problem exists there, then the monitor is bad and you should look into returning it or repairing it under warranty if possible.

If the problem doesn't exist on the new computer, then see if Windows Update installed any drivers last night. If so, see if you can roll back the driver.

If all else fails, my action of choice in these situations is usually just reinstalling the operating system.